# Will a descriptor that has been closed before being put in a fd_set be selected?

Tags: c, select

If while I put a connection descriptor in the rdset used in the `select` syscall the client closes that descriptor so it is already closed when the select is called, will it still be selected and a read/write on it return 0?

Or will it remain in the set and never be selected?

Comment: After it's closed it is no longer a file descriptor.

Comment: it's a socket, what if it is closed by the client but not by the server. Shouldn't the select receive an EOF? @stark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If while I put a connection descriptor in the rdset used in the select
>   syscall the client closes that descriptor so it is already closed when
>   the select is called, will it still be selected and a read/write on it
>   return 0?
>
> Or will it remain in the set and never be selected?

Possibly neither.  The most likely result is that the `select()` call fails, returning `-1` and setting `errno` to `EBADF`.  [Per POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html), this indicates that

> One or more of the file descriptor sets specified a file descriptor that is not a valid open file descriptor.

[The Linux manual page for select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) gives a file descriptor that was already closed as a specific example of a bad file descriptor.  *However*, the Linux manual also documents a bug that Linux `select()` ignores FDs in the provided fdsets that are greater than any that the process currently has open.  On Linux, then, you cannot rely on `select()` failing in your scenario, but if `select()` does not fail then it will never select the file descriptor in question.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX [`select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html)
requires a closed file descriptor to generate an error:

> #### ERRORS
>
> Under the following conditions, `pselect()` and `select()` shall fail and set `errno` to:
>
> [EBADF]
> One or more of the file descriptor sets specified a file descriptor that is not a valid open file descriptor.

Comment: After it has been closed, a file descriptor may be reused.

Comment: Of course, but then it is no longer a closed file descriptor; it’s just not the one you intended to select on.